# UglifyJS - how to output to a different folder?

Tags: javascript, bash, uglifyjs

I'm trying to use UglifyJS in order to minify my code but I'm running into a bit of a problem. I have a file structure like so:

```
/deploy
  /assets
    /js
      ((minified file goes here))
/js
  script-compiled.js
```

I want to run UglifyJS on `js/script-compiled.js` located in my private folder and have it output a `script.min.js` file in my `deploy/js` (the js that gets uploaded to my website) folder. Here's what I have so far for my command:

```
uglifyjs js/script-compiled.js --compress --mangle --screw-ie8 -o > deploy/assets/js/script.min.js
```

Which gives me this error:

```
fs.js:549
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
             ^

TypeError: path must be a string
```

I'm a little confused. Is it possible to output a file to a different directory? Maybe this is just a general Bash thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specified the `-o` option but you didn't provide a value. From the [docs](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS):

> `-o filename` or `--output filename` — put the result in filename. If this isn’t given, the result goes to standard output (or see next one).

So either do

```
uglifyjs ... -o deploy/assets/js/script.min.js
```

or omit `-o` and redirect stdout

```
uglifyjs ... > deploy/assets/js/script.min.js
```

Comment: ahh, removing the -o and just redirecting the stdout worked like a charm. thanks so much! :-)